# Prevent underlying button click JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-mobile, stoppropagation

Hi I have a autocomplete on my homepage on my mobile site.

When I enter text, some of the autocomplete entries will appear on top of a button.

When I click on the entry that hovers above the button, the button event is invoked.

Is it possible to change the order of the events? Because if the button event will invoke last, I can possibly use stopPropagation().

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the relevant code and markup in your question

Comment: Would disabling the button click event until the focus is off the input field meet your needs?  You could add a click event handler to the button to prevent default and then remove the handler when focus is taken off the input field.

Comment: Sorry it has been a while. @Justin Saraceno your solution worked. I've added the 'open' and 'close' event to the autocomplete with: `open: function() {
   $('#searchsubmitbtn').button('disable');
  }, close: function() {
   $('#searchsubmitbtn').button('enable');
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the best solution. Thanks@Justin Saraceno!

*Would disabling the button click event until the focus is off the input field meet your needs? You could add a click event handler to the button to prevent default and then remove the handler when focus is taken off the input field*